# Why/how do "Zalgo pings" work?

Tags: discussion, chat, zalgo

[In](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17928948#17928948) [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17938467#17938467), we decided to test whether "Zalgo pings" work, such as,

> @̮̘̮̜̤͓͓̓ͪ̓͆͗̑Ṷ̫̠̤̙̻͚̗ͭs̹͓̰̫͉̲̺̈̏̽̅̑ͩ̇̓̉e͖̝̦̦̿r͔̒̿̋̂̓n̹͖̥ͥͦͤ̍͊̏ä͇͖͚͖̃̎͊m̭͇̂͆͋̋͒e̫̠͇̰̱̦̹͗͋̓̿͒ ͔͖̫̬̗̪̪̳ͧ̄ͫB̜̥̣̬̮͈͒̄ͪ͊l̮͉̣̟̪̪̿̍ͫ͋͐̑a̜̦̪͗͗̈́ͣ͊ḫ̘̯͈̠̞͒ͯ ̣͕͚̗̠͖̫̆͌͒̓͛b̖̣͇̖̦̃̑ͬͭͥl͔͍͚͕̲̪̼͎ͧ̇̏ạ̖̪͚̯̊ͤͣͦͮ̌h̘͓͔̟͔͍̏ͣͦ̓̓ ̫̼̫ͮ͌̄ͤ̿̈͆b̙͍̼̜͍̹̬̬͎ͥ̓ͯ̂ḽ̜̟̲̾̅̆ͦ̃ͨa͇̰̝̺͊ͧͫ͛h̯̻͉̉̒̉̈́́ͥ̀.̖̩̭͇̭͔̹̈́̇͐ͬͦͦͨ̾̇.͍̪̣͂ͬ.̞͍̥̪̺̤̣̜͆ͫ̈́͑ͦ͂͑͑

Which, to my surprise, did actually ping the other user. But, why (or how) does this even work?

Since, [some](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17928972#17928972) ["Zalgo"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17938467#17938467) [messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/17938621#17938621) seem to be completely deformed, which I thought would've been enough to *not* cause the target name of the message (the `@Username` part) to match with anyone's username (due to the added Zalgo characters), and therefore not ping anyone.

Comment: You have pinged every single user on Stackoverflow with that message...and now they know it was you...

Comment: I thought that kind of annoying dross was reserved for Farcebook users only ..?

Comment: @TheBlueDog It was only an *experiment*. We don't do it all the time.

Comment: @Sam: It's all good, fella - just wondering where the hell that idea even came from.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I haven't a clue.

Comment: Great, now this question triggers the "Translate this page?" dialog in Chrome...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) reveals the effect is achieved through [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

Therefore, chances are ping works because the algorithm effectively ignores Unicode combiners when matching usernames.

Comment: Do you know if it's only combining chars that are ignored? Or, are other things disregarded as well?

Comment: Well, I'm not privy to the details, but other characters such as zero-width joiners *may* also be filtered. We would need an SE dev to get a reliable answer.

Comment: [This answer from 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49409) explained how they handled accent marks at the time; it seems to still be valid.  Regarding @sÀM's(!) question, [this Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) has more on what sort of contortions of usernames are possible without affecting the pinging effect.

Comment: I would assume it ignores accent marks, not unicode characters that are banned from usernames, otherwise @Sa(emoji)(emoji)(emoji)M would ping SAM which it doesn't (as far as I know)